# How to show different ad units on different categories

Tags: wordpress, categories, adsense

I tried to search for this on my own but couldn't find a suitable answer.

I want my wordpress site to serve different ad units on different categories. For example I have made 6 ad units, A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3. I want A1 A2 & A3 to show on pages tagged in "Category A" and B1 B2 & B3 ad units to show on any other category pages.

I am inserting the ad code directly in the single.php's content loop. In future, I will need to show different ad units in upto 4 different categories.

Basically, I am creating niche-specific ad units for advertisers to bid.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As far I am aware, advertisers could bid on your custom channels, not on specific ad units. See "[Ad placement and how to create it](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/160534?hl=en)" page.

So, I would do this:

- **www.google.com/adsense > My ads > Content > Custom channels**:

  - create one custom channel for category "A"
  - and one ("default") for other
    pages (you can consider, and threat it as your "channel B")
  - get those channels IDs, for example `"default"="1111111111"` and `"A"="2222222222"`
- **WordPress dashboard categories**:

  - get "A" category ID, for example  `"A" = 5`

First, get the channel ID for current category:

```
<?php
$google_adsense_custom_channel = "1111111111";
if ( in_category( 5 ) ) {
  $google_adsense_custom_channel = "2222222222";
}
?>
```

And then you can start printing the ad tags with that ID as `data-ad-channel`:

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
  style="display:block;"
  data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234"
  data-ad-slot="5678"
  data-ad-channel="<?php echo $google_adsense_custom_channel; ?>"
  data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>
```

Or - if you prefer your implementation to look [like the official AdSense Help Center examples](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736?hl=en):

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
  style="display:block;"
  data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234"
  data-ad-slot="5678"
  data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
    params: { google_ad_channel: "<?php echo $google_adsense_custom_channel; ?>" }
  });
</script>
```

(Note: you need quotes around channel ID, because channel ID, for example `0123456789`, is string.)

Comment: I think your last example is the best method